# c++/error :: exc_bad_access error code=1

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error, exc-bad-access

Im getting a runtime error of exc_bad_access ( code = 1, address=0x0) on line

```
asize = **y[0] + **y[1];
```

in the summation function.
I know the problem is not a memory leak, so i don't quite know how to go about solving this problem.

```
void allocArr (int **&x, int ***&y, int **&q, int ****&z)
{
    x = new int *[2];
    y = new int **(&*x);
    q = &*x;
    z = new int ***(&q);
}

void summation(int ***&y, int arr[])
{
    int asize = 0;
    asize = **y[0] + **y[1];
    **y[2] = *new int [asize];

    *(arr + 2) = asize;

}

void putArr(int **&x, const int &size1,const int &size2)
{
    x[0] = *new int* [size1];

    x[1] = *new int* [size2];

}
int main()
{
    int size1, size2;
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    int** x;
    int*** y;
    int** q;
    int**** z;

    int arr[2];

    allocArr(x, y, q, z);
    Input(x, arr, size1, size2, a, b);
    summation(y, arr);
    display(z);


}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish with this code?  This thing has more stars than the Milky Way.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? This looks like some really extraneous use of *****.

Comment: y doesn't seem to be set to a value at any point.

Comment: i am trying to store the values in the array pointed to by y in the variable asize

Answer (score 0):

Three things.
1.)The function arguments for y are int ***& . Did you overload int with a bracket operator somewhere else? As specified, the int pointer should not have a [].
2.) Bracket operators are higher in precedence than a dereference operator. (Almost always a good idea to enclose them within parenthesis). The way this is written, the bracket operator will be performed before the deref.
3.) It seems unusual that you should need so many dereference operators. Are they really necessary?

Comment: sadly the whole point of this program is to use multiple level indirection, as specified by my professor.