# c++ error :: EXC_BAD_ACCESS for pointer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, runtime-error, exc-bad-access

I keep getting the error message, exc_bad_access code=1 for my line

```
asize = *(***(y) + **(y + 1));
```

in the summation function. I dont quite understand what to do with this error, but i know that it is not a memory leak. 
I am trying to get the values stored in the y pointer array, add them, and store it in the variable asize.

```
void allocArr (int **&x, int ***&y, int **&q, int ****&z)
{
    x = new int *[2];
    y = new int **(&*x);
    q = &*x;
    z = new int ***(&q);
}


void putArr(int **&x, int &size1, int &size2)
{
    *(x) = *new int* [size1];

    *(x + 1) = *new int* [size2];

}

void Input (int **&x, int *&arr, int &size1,int &size2, int a, int b)
{

    cout << "Please enter 2 non-negative integer values: "<< endl;

    checkVal(size1, a);
    checkVal(size2, b);
    putArr(x, size1, size2);

    arr[0] = size1;
    arr[1] = size2;

    cout << x[0];
}


void summation(int ***&y, int *&arr)
{
    int asize = 0;
    asize = *(***(y) + **(y + 1));
    **y[2] = *new int [asize];

    *(arr + 2) = asize;

}

int main()
{
    int size1, size2;
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    int** x;
    int*** y;
    int** q;
    int**** z;

    int *arr = new int [2];

    allocArr(x, y, q, z);
    Input(x, arr, size1, size2, a, b);
    summation(y, arr);
    display(z);


}
```

Thank you for the help. Im really struggling here...

Comment: When there are more asterisks than letters, you know something's wrong. *I am trying to get the values stored in the y pointer array, add them, and store it in the variable asize.* - Use a `std::vector<int>` for the "pointer array" and use `std::accumulate` to calculate the sum. I'm willing to bet there is no reason at all to use pointers anywhere in this code.

Comment: You asked the question already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755906/c-error-exc-bad-access-error-code-1.  And your professor is playing a mean joke on you and your classmates.

Comment: That solution is horrible! If you are trying to do nD arrays, check boost multiarray structures for that: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got started with the code. The code can be simplified quite a bit to help you, and readers of your code, understand what's going on.

**Function `allocArr`**

The lines

```
y = new int **(&*x);
q = &*x;
```

can be

```
y = new int **(x);  // &*x == x
q = x;
```

**Function `putArr`**

You have the function declaration as:

```
void putArr(int **&x, int &size1, int &size2)
```

It can be changed to:

```
void putArr(int **x, int size1, int size2)
```

without changing how you are using the variables.

Your code in the function seems strange. Did you mean for `x[0]` and `x[1]` to point to an array of `size1` and `size2` `int`s, respectively? If you did, the code would be:

```
x[0] = new int[size1];
x[1] = new int[size2];
```

If you don't mean the above, it's hard to figure out what you are trying to do with your code.

**Function `Input`**

You have the function declaration as:

```
void Input (int **&x, int *&arr, int &size1,int &size2, int a, int b)
```

It can be changed to:

```
void Input (int **x, int *arr, int &size1,int &size2, int a, int b)
```

without changing how you are using the variables.

You are calling a function `checkVal`, but your posted code doesn't have that function. It's not clear what that function is doing. You have the line

```
cout << "Please enter 2 non-negative integer values: "<< endl;
```

just before the calls to `checkVal`. Presumably, `checkVal` reads the input and stores them in `size1` in the first call and `size2` in the second call. It's not clear how the second argument to `checkVal` is used.

And then, you have the line:

```
cout << x[0];
```

It's not clear what you wish to accomplish from printing an `int*` to `cout`. Perhaps it was part of your debugging code. The line doesn't change anything else in the program. It's just strange to see it there.

**Function `summation`**

You have the function declaration as:

```
void summation(int ***&y, int *&arr)
```

It can be changed to:

```
void summation(int ***y, int *arr)
```

without changing how you are using the variables.

In this function, you have the expression:

```
asize = *(***(y) + **(y + 1));
```

What do you get when you evaluate `***(y)`?

```
***(y) = **(*y) = **(x) = *(*x) = *(x[0]) = uninitialized value from the line:

x[0] = new int[size1];
```

You will get unpredictable behavior when you use an uninitialized value.

The second term of the line, `**(y + 1)` is the worse culprit.

You allocated memory for `y` as:

```
y = new int **(&*x);
```

It's a pointer to a single object of type `int**`, not an array. `y+1` is not a valid pointer. Dereferencing `(y+1)` leads to undefined behavior. In your case, you are seeing `exc_bad_access`, which makes sense now since you are accessing memory that is out of bounds.

Since I don't know what you are trying to compute in that expression, it's hard for me to suggest something useful. I hope you have enough to take it from here.